# req.body getting twice on 307 redirect in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, http-redirect

I've got a strange problem with my form to submit un express js application.

When the user submits  a form some data is `POST` to another route and redirect to the same route.

**View**

```
<form action="action" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When the user submits `action` route is triggered

```
const action = function action(req,res){

    //make a post request 
    requestify.request('http://localhost:3005/idg/webhook', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            foo: 'bar',
            bar: 'foo'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .then(function(response) {

    });
    //redirect to the same route
     res.redirect(307,'http://localhost:3005/idg/webhook');

}
```

Here is the `idg/webhook` route

```
const webhook = function webhook(req,res){
    console.log("body",req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
}
```

The problem is I am getting two `req.body` in `idg/webhook` route.

`console.log("body",req.body)` from `idg/webhook`

```
body { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' }
body { submit: 'submit' }
```

As you see I am able to get two `req.body` why this is happening?? I need only the `req.body`  ie `{ foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' }`

Answer (score 0):

remove name from input submit , change as follow :

```
<form action="action" method="post">
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Still, i am getting the two `req.body`